# PDF dynamically on IE

Tags: jquery, html, css, pdf

I`m trying to display a PDF dynamically. My code is working fine on Firefox, Chrome.

Only on IE it`s not working.

My HTML:

```
<a id="link" class="pdf" href="./pdf/5/5a0ae9f13c291.pdf?id=1550811">
   <div class="container_date">
     <h1>14</h1>
     <h2>November</h2>
     <h4>2017</h4>
   </div>
</a>
```

Im displaying my PDF File in:

```
<div class="pdf_wrapper">
   <div class="pdf_container">
       <div class="pdf_frame_close">
          <img src="images/icons/to_home.png">
       </div>
        <object data=""></object>
    </div>
</div>'
```

My jQuery to manipulate the PDF-Data Source is:

```
$(".pdf").click(function(event)
{
var link = this.href;
event.preventDefault(event);
if(!isMobile.any())
{
    link += '#toolbar=0&navpanes=0&scrollbar=0';
    $('.pdf_container object').attr('data', link);
    $('.pdf_wrapper').show();
}
else
{
    window.location.href = link;
}
});
```

Is there any solution to get it work on IE?

**EDIT**
I Just tested my PDF-WRAPPER. When i set the default data="./pdf/5/5a0ae9f13c291.pdf?id=1550811" and do not change it via jQuery it works fine. But i need to change it via jQuery on Click...

Answer (score 0):

Please try below:

Tools>Internet Options>security tab, click "reset all zones to default"

Tools>ActiveX filtering (turn it off)

Tools>Manage addons>Show all addons

-> locate your installed PDF Reader addons and ensure they are enabled.

->Adobe PDF Reader 10 and earlier have an option/setting to "Display PDF in the browser"

Web documents opened with the 'file:' protocol require a mark of the web to run Active Content.

The latest IE11 update adds additional security for iframe hosted pdf documents.

MSIE browsers don't support object hosted pdf or xps content. The common design pattern is a named or Id'd iframe.

Reference:- https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/ie/en-US/298a4323-0190-4a4a-ae88-447ced39032e/how-to-display-embedded-pdf-in-internet-explorer-11-ie11?forum=iewebdevelopment